# Formik setValues() throws 'Too many re-renders' error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, rerender

I am trying to use `setValues` to clear ONLY SOME KEYS in the Formik form in the function `clearCurrentEntries`, but no matter what I do, I get the error `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` I have also tried calling the `clearCurrentEntries` in the `showInput` function, but no matter where I put it, I get the same rerenders exceeded error.

- How do I clear some values in Formik state, but prevent the app from rerendering too many times and throwing this error?

```
const Container = () => {
  const emptyObj = {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    middle_name: '',
  }

  const clearCurrentEntries = (values, setValues) => {
    setValues({ ...values, ...emptyObj })
  }
  const showInput = (values) => {
    const msOptions = ['one', 'two', '']
    const ms = values?.status?.toLowerCase()
    const show = msOptions.every((option) => ms !== option)
    return show
  }

  return 
    <div>
      <Formik
        enabledReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={formStructure}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values, setFieldValue, setValues }) => {
          return (
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
              <div className="form-content">
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label>Status</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    as="select"
                    id={'status'}
                    name={'status'}
                    value={values?.status}
                    onChange={handleChange}>
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    {statusOptions.map((option) => (
                      <option key={option} value={option}>
                        {option}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
                {showInput(values) ? (
                  <CurrentInputs />
                ) : (
                  clearCurrentEntries(values, setValues)
                )}
            </Form>
          )
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Container
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if im wrong but your clear function dosent actually clear a thing but instead adds.

```
const clearCurrentEntries = (values, setValues) => {
  setValues({ ...values, ...emptyObj })
}
```

You are passint `values` - ALL the values that exist in your object. Also a method `setValues` that sets the value of the entire object.

In your function, that receives all that, you are executing `setValues` function and passint ALL currently available data inside the object and combining it with `emptyObj` object data.

After all this, it updates your state hence re-renders the components. But since the new value was the same old value + just `emptyObj` object, it did not remove the unwanted value so it triggers your same function that executes exactly the same logic.

Could be easier to figure out the issue by knowing what the function gets as `values`. But if my theory is correct, simply commenting the area with `showInput` should stop trowing this error. If so - I was right.

In that case, a simple fix could be done by simply instead of removing it, just dont render it.

```
{showInput(values) && <CurrentInputs />}
```

If you do require it to be removed, that can be accomplished too but sadly without knowing what the `values` are and how its being stores, with my limited low knowladge, I can not predict what to do and how. If you would Update your post with the `values`

The point of this was to try to identify why and where the issue accures.

Comment: The setValues function works as expected by maintaining and updating the appropriate values in Formik state. It just throws the re-rendering err in the process. Whether I create one new updated state obj or update the values in the way I do above w/ emptyObj, the same error occurs.

Comment: The error is caused because its constantly re-rendering. this is being caused because of state constantly updating. When a state is updated, it causes the component to re-render. if, while re-rendering, the state updates again - re-render again. In your case, the re-renders never end meaning that after every re-render the state automatically updates AGAIN and again. `values` is a state, in your case, and `setValues` sets the value and triggers the re-render. [1/3]

Comment: and the function is ONLY being triggered, as seen in your example, by `clearCurrentEntries` method. Hence why its kinda first thing to assume that is the issue. If removing this entire component it fixed the issue, then the only thing triggering the re-render is `setValues` in `clearCurrentEntries`. So what I expected, and seeing form the code, is that the `clearCurrentEntries` does NOT clear the value, or values, from `values` variable that triggerer the `if` statement in render, hence every single time re-rendering it enters the `if` statement again and again [2/3]

Comment: If my hypothesis is right, commenting out 
`{showInput(values) ? (
<CurrentInputs />
) : (
clearCurrentEntries(values, setValues)
)}`, 
and making `show` always true, so it renders in what you need, for the time, will temporary resolve it.  If so, then fixing up `clearCurrentEntries`, as I mentioned, will solve your issues for good. Please try it, as its most likely to be the issue. I udnerstand that I might have written something that caused a miss-understanding at 'why', most likely because of my terrible english, if so - coment to what and ill fix the post (if it solves the issue)